# Countries are not visible with pst-map3d

Tags: pstricks

Currently I am trying to use `pst-map3d` package. The code below plots the earth ball but doesn't draw the countries / country lines.

I tried the code now on a Windows, Linux and Mac machine and every time I receive the same results.

The data of the package is copied to `C:/data/pst-geo/data`. For compiling I use the `LaTeX->dvips->ps2pdf`-chain.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-map3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\WorldMapThreeD[PHI=30,
                THETA=0,
                Decran=15,
                path=C:/data/pst-geo/data]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The code produces following plot:

[image: output]

The output shows **one** error (for Windows 8 machine).

```
Process started: latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode "temp".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: dvips.exe -o "temp".ps "temp".dvi

This is dvips(k) 5.994 Copyright 2014 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2015.02.06:0040' -> temp.ps <C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/tex.pro>

<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pst-node/pst-node.pro> <C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pst-geo/pst-map3d.pro>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pst-barcode/pst-barcode.pro>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/texps.pro>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/special.pro> <C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/color.pro>.
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb> [1
]

Process exited normally


Process started: ps2pdf.exe "temp".ps

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript

9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Process exited normally
```

Is there maybe an error with my LaTeX code?

Comment: Try running `ps2pdf` manually at the command line to see if you get more information. Weird that it says the process exited normally - it seems not very good at recognising the error!

Comment: for the ghostscript run (ps2pdf) you need the optional argument `-dNOSAFER`. Otherwise it do not load the external data files

Comment: @Herbert, thank you. `-dNOSAFER` solves the problem. You should post it as an answer that I can declare it as the solution.

Comment: @larkee: yes, done ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the `ghostscript` run (`ps2pdf`) you need the optional argument `-dNOSAFER`. Otherwise it do not load the external data files.